# Вернуть false в случае возникновения исключения при соединении с БД

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rethinkdb

Мое REST-приложение должно отправлять статус соединения с БД по запросу. В синглтоне, хранящем соединений, я сделал возможность реконнекта при обрыве соединения:

```
package zunami.repository;

import com.rethinkdb.RethinkDB;
import com.rethinkdb.net.Connection;

public class DBConnector {

    private static DBConnector instance;
    private Connection connection;

    private DBConnector() {
        connection = RethinkDB.r.connection().connect();
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

    public static DBConnector getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DBConnector();
        }
        else if (!instance.getConnection().isOpen()) {
            instance = new DBConnector();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Этот класс будет использоваться в репозиториях.

Контроллер для обработки запроса статуса приложения написан так:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class HealthController {

    @Autowired
    private Connection conn;

    @GetMapping("/health")
    public HealthResponse health() {
        conn = DBConnector.getInstance().getConnection();
        return HealthResponse.of(conn.isOpen());
    }


    private static class HealthResponse {

        private boolean ok;
        private boolean rethinkDB;
        private String version;

        public static HealthResponse of (boolean connectionStatus) {
            return new HealthResponse(connectionStatus);
        }

        private HealthResponse(boolean status) {
            this.ok = status;
            this.rethinkDB = status;
            this.version = "1.2.7";
        }

        public boolean isOk() {
            return ok;
        }

        public void setOk(boolean ok) {
            this.ok = ok;
        }

        public boolean isRethinkDB() {
            return rethinkDB;
        }

        public void setRethinkDB(boolean rethinkDB) {
            this.rethinkDB = rethinkDB;
        }

        public String getVersion() {
            return version;
        }

        public void setVersion(String version) {
            this.version = version;
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема состоит в том, что если я запрашиваю статус приложения в тот момент, когда БД упала, возвращается не статус соединения false, а текст исключения `java.net.ConnectException`. Если БД не лежит и соединение установилось корректно, то возвращается true, как задумано.

Как я могу использовать свой синглтон так, чтобы контроллер отправлял не текст исключения, а результат вызова метода Connection.isOpen?

Завернуть вызов синглтона в try-catch не получается.

Comment: а почему не получается вызов `conn = DBConnector.getInstance().getConnection();` завернуть в try/catch?

Comment: @zolt, компилятор сообщает, что этот код не выбрасывает данное исключение

Comment: можно ловить вообще все исключения, указав в блоке `catch(Exception e) {}`. Делать так не рекомендуют, но в Вашем случае это оправдано

Comment: @zolt, это исключение почему-то все равно вылетает из try-catch блока, даже если ловить Throwable

Comment: Попробовал `try {
            conn = DBConnector.getInstance().getConnection();
            return HealthResponse.of(conn.isOpen());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return HealthResponse.of(false);
        }` возвращается HealthResponse, а не не текст исключения. А как вы определяете бин Connection?

Comment: @SpringNewbie, да, все работает